# How to realize a more complex initial_state for LSTM in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, lstm

I am currently working with multilayer LSTM using tensorflow and python.
I am passing the previous state of the cells to the next step using *initial_state* in tf.nn.dynamic_rnn.

Creating the layers like that:

```
cells = []
for c in range(0, num_layers):
    cells.append(tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units = num_units, forget_bias = 1.0, activation = tf.nn.tanh))
basic_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells)
state_series, current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32, initial_state = rnn_tuple_state)
```

With types and dimensions like that:

```
rnn_tuple_state: <class 'tuple'>                                                len:num_layers
  Layer  0 : <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl.LSTMStateTuple'>       len:2
     cell: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>                     dimensions:(outputs, truncated_backprop_len)
     hidden: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>                   dimensions:(outputs, truncated_backprop_len)
  Layer 1 : ...
  ...
  Layer num_layers : ...

state_series: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>                  dimension:(outputs, truncated_backprop_len, num_units)
current_state: <class 'tuple'>                                                  len:num_layers
    Layer 0 : <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl.LSTMStateTuple'>      len:2
       cell_state: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> (7, 360)    dimensions:(outputs, truncated_backprop_len)
       hidden_state: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> (7, 360)  dimensions:(outputs, truncated_backprop_len)
    Layer 1 : ...
    ...
    Layer num_layers: ...
```

Using this I was able to realize state-space LSTM looking like that:

[simple_initial-state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbYlq.png)

In the picture in blue are the zero_state, in green the 2 LSTM-layers, the columns are all the same cells and should only show the recurrences, the arrows shows the passing of the states from one step to the next.

Now I want to use a more complex initial_state, passing states not only from one step to the next but also from one layer to the other like that:

[wanted complex initial_state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSzfs.png)

**And that is where I got stuck now**.
I played around a bit with just adding additional tuples to the initial_state but that leads me just to errors like *ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)*. 
I was also looking at other types of LSTM-cells but was not able to identify the needed.

So my question is, how can I realize this more complex initial_state in tensorflow, e.g. which cell types to use or how to shape the initial_state?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your cell state must be a single vector of numbers which has to be of the size defined in the LSTM cell. The LSTM cell will output the same size as it expects for its input. When you have multiple layers you are generally passing information from one layer to the next via the output of the first layer to the input of the second layer. You don't generally pass the state up. However, if you want to experiment in this way, I suppose the way to do it would be to add the two states together, as you can't really change the shape. You might consider the precedence of residual networks as justification for such an idea (though I have no idea if it's a good idea or not).

If you want to output a different cell state size than you input so that you can actually concatenate the state of the layer before, within the input cell state, you are going to have to code the RNN by hand, no LSTM cell wrapper is going to allow this kind of configuration.

To get a better sense of the internals of the LSTM cell I'd read up here:

http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

Comment: Thank you a lot. Merging the states together is a nice idea!